# iRobot Create 2 to Vacuum?

Tags: irobot-create

I just got a Create 2 for Christmas, and while I'm planning to create with it (obviously), I'd like to use it around the house as a vacuum if at all possible. I've heard that you can buy parts for the Roomba and throw them on to this chassis, but I wanted to confirm/refute that before I bought anything. Is that possible or am I crazy?

Comment: I voted to close this as a shopping request - a [sales rep from iRobot](http://homesupport.irobot.com/app/chat/chat_launch) could answer this question. There is no actual problem to solve.

Comment: The sales rep I spoke with (via chat) refused to disclose the parts list required.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can buy Roomba 600 accessories from [store.irobot.com](http://store.irobot.com/family/index.jsp?categoryId=13271022&cp=3744764) to turn your Create2 back into a working vacuum.  Note however that there is no way to "cheat the system".  While the Create2 is cheaper than the Roomba 650, it will cost you way more in spare parts to return its vacuuming functionality than if you had just bought a 650 in the first place.

Comment: Ben, can specify which parts we need to buy? I have the same situation. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to *robotics* Roquito, but on Stack exchange *answers* need to answer the question. If you wish to discuss a question or answer you can ask about it on [chat]. If you have a suggestion as to how a question or answer can be improved, you can comment when you have [comment everywhere](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) privileges. If there is a serious problem with a question or answer, and you do not have enough reputation to comment on it, you can flag it for moderator attention. Take a look at [ask] and [about] for more information on how stack exchange works.*